# How to get aws sqs client and send a message to queue?

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

How to get aws sqs client and send a message to queue in ruby sdk?

```
$sqs = Aws::SQS::Client.new(
  :access_key_id => SQS_CONFIG[:access_key_id], 
  :secret_access_key => SQS_CONFIG[:secret_access_key], 
  :region => 'us-east-1'
)
```

After this how to push message to a queue?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [examples for the Ruby SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/developer-guide/sqs-example-send-and-receive-messages.html)?

Comment: I need fifo queue. Aws::SQS::Errors::MissingParameter (The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.):

Answer (score 2):

From the [AWS Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/developer-guide/sqs-example-send-and-receive-messages.html)

```
require 'aws-sdk'

sqs = Aws::SQS::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')

# Send a message to a queue.
queue_name = "my-queue"

begin
  queue_url = sqs.get_queue_url(queue_name: queue_name).queue_url

  # Create a message with three custom attributes: Title, Author, and WeeksOn.
  send_message_result = sqs.send_message({
    queue_url: queue_url, 
    message_body: "Information about current NY Times fiction bestseller for week of 2016-12-11.",
    message_attributes: {
      "Title" => {
        string_value: "The Whistler",
        data_type: "String"
      },
      "Author" => {
        string_value: "John Grisham",
        data_type: "String"
      },
      "WeeksOn" => {
        string_value: "6",
        data_type: "Number"
      }
    }
  })
rescue Aws::SQS::Errors::NonExistentQueue
  puts "A queue named '#{queue_name}' does not exist."
  exit(false)
end

puts send_message_result.message_id
```

Comment: In SDK v1, there is a method poll to poll from the queue infinitely. How can i achieve that in V2? @robbie-chiha

Comment: v2: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SQS/QueuePoller.html
v3: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/SQS/QueuePoller.html